# Stronger convergence in the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, almost-everywhere

In the proof I have of the CLT theorem, we use the fact that, for $(X_i)_{i\geqslant 1}$ a sequence of iid random variables in $L^2(\mathbb{P})$, we have
$$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\Phi_{Z_n}(u)=\exp\left(-\frac{u^2\sigma^2}{2}\right)$$
where $\Phi$ is the characteristic function, and
$$Z_n=\sqrt{n}\left(\overline{X_n}-\mathbb{E}\left[X_1\right]\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$$
where $Y_i=X_i-\mathbb{E}\left[X_i\right]$.

However, it is legitimate to wonder whether there exists a random variable $Z$ such that $Z_n$ converges to $Z$ almost surely. If that is the case, because $Z_n$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, then we must have $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.

But I have no way to go further. I have read somewhere that we can use the sequence
$$Z_n'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}Y_i$$

Indeed, this converges on distribution to a random variable $G$ such that $G\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.
But what is the link between $Z_n$ and $Z_n'$ ? If $Z_n$ converges almost surely to some random variable $Z$, then what is the limit (almost surely) of $Z_n'$ ?

Comment: Note that $Var(Z_n) = Var(X_1)$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.  You wouldn't expect $Z_n$ to converge to anything.  And it can be shown that it does not.  You can use $Z_n'$, which is independent of $Z_n$ but has the same distribution as $Z_n$, to show it does not.

Comment: If i remember correctly, then it can be showed, that if $\sigma^2 > 0$, then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_n$ does not converge in probability and hence not almost surely nor in $\mathcal{L}^p$ for any $p\geq 1$, so in a sense the CLT for $i.i.d.$ random variables cannot be improved upon.

Comment: @Michael What is the correct way to use $Z'_n$ to show that $Z_n$ does not converge almost surely then ? I wanted to compute what is the limit of $Z'_n$ in terms of the limits of $Z_n$ (if it converged almost surely to a random variable $Z$) but I could not find anything. Any hints ?

Comment: $Z_{2n} = \frac{Z_n + Z_n'}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: @Michael Thank you, this indeed helps to conclude. If you use it as an answer, for the post, I'll accept it if you want.